# Php: loop breaks when call a method inside a while in a class

Tags: php, class, while-loop

I have a problem in a class I can't solve, the loop breaks in getAlojamiento() when I call getImagenes() inside the while. In this case getAlojamiento() returns only one row, it should return all the rows. Here are the methods involved:

```
 //THIS GETS THE ROWS FROM A TABLE AND RETURN AN ARRAY, IF $id IS SET, CHECKS IF id_asoc == $id
 public function getImagenes($table, $id=false){
    $return = '';
    //checks if id id == true
    if($id){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id_asoc = '$id' ORDER BY id DESC";
    }else{
        $id = '';
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
    //this make the sql request (returns an array)
    if(!$this->MySQLQuery($sql)){
        $return = false;
        }else{
        if($this->dbNumberRows == 0){ //cheks if there are results
            $return = false;
        }else{ //if has results makes and fills an array
            $items = array();
            while($f = mysql_fetch_object($this->dbResults)){
                $items[$f->id]['id'] = $f->id;
                $items[$f->id]['id_asoc'] = $f->id_asoc;
                $items[$f->id]['comentario'] = htmlentities($f->comentario);
                $items[$f->id]['nombre'] = htmlentities($f->nombre);
                }
            $return = $items;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}


 //THIS GETS THE ROWS FROM A TABLE AND RETURN AN ARRAY
   public function getAlojamiento($id=false){
        $return = '';
        //checks if id id == true 
        if($id){
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_alojamiento WHERE id = '$id'  LIMIT 1";
        }else{
            $id = '';
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_alojamiento ORDER BY titulo ASC";
        }
    //this make the sql request (returns an array)
    if(!$this->MySQLQuery($sql)){
        $return = false;
        }else{
        if($this->dbNumberRows == 0){ //cheks if there are results
            $return = false;
        }else{ //if has results makes and fills an array
            $items = array();
            while($f = mysql_fetch_object($this->dbResults)){
                $imagenes_arr = $this->getImagenes('tb_alo_imagenes', $f->id); //this is causing the break
                $items[$f->id]['id'] = $f->id;
                $items[$f->id]['titulo'] = $f->titulo;
                $items[$f->id]['telefono'] = $f->telefono;
                $items[$f->id]['descripcion'] = $f->descripcion;
                $items[$f->id]['email'] = $f->email;
                $items[$f->id]['url'] = $f->url;
                $items[$f->id]['direccion'] = $f->direccion;
                $items[$f->id]['ubicacion'] = $f->ubicacion;
                $items[$f->id]['coordenadas'] = $f->coordenadas;
                $items[$f->id]['disponibilidad'] = $f->disponibilidad;
                $items[$f->id]['tarifas'] = $f->tarifas;
                $items[$f->id]['servicios'] = $f->servicios;
                $items[$f->id]['theme'] = $f->theme;
                $items[$f->id]['premium'] = $f->premium;
                $items[$f->id]['img_ppal_id'] = $f->img_ppal_id;    
                $items[$f->id]['imagenes'] = $imagenes_arr;


            }
            $return = $items;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to avoid having the first mysql query affect other queries is to complete it first:

```
//first loop over the result set from first query

while($f = mysql_fetch_object($this->dbResults))
{
    //note: no call to $this->getImagenes here!
    $items[$f->id]['id'] = $f->id;
    $items[$f->id]['titulo'] = $f->titulo;
    ....
}

//only now you fetch the images in a second pass 

foreach( $items as $id => $item )
{
    $items[$id]['imagenes'] = $this->getImagenes('tb_alo_imagenes', $id);
}

//return the complete $items array

$return = $items;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `$this->dbResults` for both queries. When you call `getImagenes` you are clobbering the `dbResults` in `getAlojamiento`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And how should I fix it?

Comment: You'll need to make sure you use two separate results objects when you do the second query. Perhaps make `$this->MySQLQuery($sql)` return the results object which you can then use rather than storing it in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
            while($f = mysql_fetch_object($this->dbResults)){
                $items[$f->id]['id'] = $f->id;
                $items[$f->id]['id_asoc'] = $f->id_asoc;
                $items[$f->id]['comentario'] = htmlentities($f->comentario);
                $items[$f->id]['nombre'] = htmlentities($f->nombre);
                }
            $return[] = $items;
```

You're setting the array to be the single $items array.  You need to add it to the $return array.

Comment: This is shorthand for adding $items to the end of the $return array.